# Find and remove too large of files to push in git lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a commit, and I am trying to push it.  I get this response

```
Git LFS: (0 of 9 files, 9 skipped) 0 B / 3.24 GB, 3.24 GB skipped
[422] Size must be less than 2147483648
[0ee4f2bc4d42d98ea0e7b5aeba2762c7482f3bcf00739d40b922babe8061820b] Size must be less than 2147483648
error: failed to push some refs to ...
```

What files are these?

How can I find and remove them from my commit so I can push all these files up?

Comment: One way would be to call `git status` and if these are few files check them one to one. Other suggestion based on filesystem tools like find with a size option ... your choice. HTH

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple

```
git ls-files
```

will give you a listing of files currently managed by git.

With a bit of pipe magic, the file over size limit get's pretty easy to spot

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 stat -c '%s %n' | sort -n
```

will give you an ascendingly sorted list of file sizes and corresponding files.

Comment: The list seems to work nice.  I saw the two largest files looked like this    `419024639 backups/14_12_2015.zip
2921741563 backups/18_04_2016.zip
`    I then ran `git reset HEAD^ backups/18_04_2016.zip` and `git reset HEAD^ backups/14_12_2015.zip` then `git commit -c ORIG_HEAD` then `git push origin master -f` .  I still get the same error.  Do you know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the default push behaviour in this particular case. Possibly, you're still pushing history containing the full in size

Comment: I needed to use `git reset --soft HEAD~2` to get it to work for me

Comment: This command does not work for me. Is it for Linux only? I'm on Windows...

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland no, that's got nothing to do with the OS you're on. It might depend on the shell and environment you're using – on Linux systems, you'd typically find `xargs` and `sort` already installed, on Windows you'd usually install it with a shell you use for git. Windows is always a bit underequipped when it comes to tooling.

Comment: In git bash on Windows, I get `stat: missing operand` when using the command `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 stat -c '%s %n' | sort -n `

Comment: that means there's no files that `git ls-files` reports. Wrong directory?

Comment: @softwareisfun *which* xargs on windows? There's dozens of ways of getting an `xargs` executable that runs on windows...

Comment: `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 stat -c '%s %n' | numfmt --to=iec | sort -h` for human-readable sizes.